# how can this be responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, swiper.js

I tried 100% width but had no luck as it does not comply. anyone pls guide me. the swiper sometimes comes over the text it doesn't stay in the column. in mobile or tablet, I want them to be filling the screen with swiper slides and rest when you scroll down.in mobile view everything gets cut once i reach 528px any help
in mobile i want it to look like shown in image[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of7Ra.png)

```js
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
          spaceBetween: 10,
          slidesPerView: 4,
          freeMode: true,
          watchSlidesProgress: true,
        });
        var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
          spaceBetween: 10,
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
          thumbs: {
            swiper: galleryThumbs
          }
        });
```

```css
ul.breadcrumb {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 568px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "/\00a0";
}
ul.breadcrumb li a {
    color: #0275d8;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
    color: #01447e;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.product{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.page-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 622px;
    grid-column-gap: 21px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 538px;
    height: 725px;
}
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
  
.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
  
.gallery-top {
    height: 78%;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs {
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 18%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

  
.box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.product-title{
    font-size: 28px;
}
  
.box3 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    min-height: 200px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .page-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="product">
        <div class="page-container"> <!-- Container -->
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Column 1 (Swiper) -->
                <!-- Swiper -->
                <div class="swiper gallery-top">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper gallery-thumbs">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <!-- Column 2 (Details) -->
            <div class="box2">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Desert Safari</a></li>
                    <li>Morning Safari</li>
                </ul>
                <h1 class="product-title">Morning Safari</h1>
                
            </div>
          
           
            <!-- Content that spans two rows -->
            <div class="box3">
                Content that spans two rows
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So typically my approach, when I am faced with something like this, would be to add `media queries` and make sure that the `page-container` div is not a grid display in those queries. For example, what I would do is give it flex at a certain width and change the flex-direction from row to column, and align the items in the center. Using this `flex-direction: column;` is great for mobile devices.

```js
var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
          spaceBetween: 10,
          slidesPerView: 4,
          freeMode: true,
          watchSlidesProgress: true,
        });
        var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
          spaceBetween: 10,
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
          thumbs: {
            swiper: galleryThumbs
          }
        });
```

```css
ul.breadcrumb {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 568px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
}
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "/\00a0";
}
ul.breadcrumb li a {
    color: #0275d8;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
    color: #01447e;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.product{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.page-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 622px;
    grid-column-gap: 21px;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 538px;
    height: 725px;
}
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
  
.swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
  
.gallery-top {
    height: 78%;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs {
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 18%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
  
.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

  
.box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.product-title{
    font-size: 28px;
}
  
.box3 {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    min-height: 200px;
}
  
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .page-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
.swiper-container {
    width: 450px;
    height: 725px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="product">
        <div class="page-container"> <!-- Container -->
            <div class="swiper-container">
                <!-- Column 1 (Swiper) -->
                <!-- Swiper -->
                <div class="swiper gallery-top">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper gallery-thumbs">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg)"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <!-- Column 2 (Details) -->
            <div class="box2">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Desert Safari</a></li>
                    <li>Morning Safari</li>
                </ul>
                <h1 class="product-title">Morning Safari</h1>
                
            </div>
          
           
            <!-- Content that spans two rows -->
            <div class="box3">
                Content that spans two rows
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```